# Can't set NumberFormat with Excel JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I'm using the excel Javascript API and after searching through the docs, still can't find a solution for what I'm trying to achieve.

So I want to set everything to have the number format "Text" so none of Excel's auto-formatting messes with any of the cells' content (no removing leading zeros or changing date formats).

The docs suggest changing the format via:

`Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A17").NumberFormat = "General"`

But it seems the sheet object doesn't contain a Range method.

Instead I tried to use the getRange method on my table like this:

`constructionTable.getRange().NumberFormat = "Text"`

This didn't throw any errors, but didn't seem to do anything.

Formatting the table range had previously worked for stuff like this:

`constructionTable.getRange().format.autofitColumns()`

So I also checked whether `constructionTable.getRange().range.format` contains a method called NumberFormat or numberFormat, but it does not :(

Has anyone had any success doing this?

Comment: Side note: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A17").NumberFormat = "General"` is VBA, not the JS API.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Office JS, Tluther. Yes, worksheet dont have `numberFormat` API. if you want to set the whole sheet, you could use `getUsedRange()` to get the range that used in the worksheet. You can use range.numberFormat = '@' to set it to text;

Here is the sample code:

```
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sample");

    const range = sheet.getUsedRange();
    range.numberFormat = '@';
    await context.sync();
  });
```

Document can be found at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#numberformat)

Comment: @ worked fine, but I can't seem to get it to do anything else how about numbers or currency can you give one or two more examples?

Comment: `range.numberFormat = '0';` also worked for me for #'s thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Now, the API numberFormat now should use format like '[][]', So how can l set the 'accounting' or 'general' by JS API.